# Identify fuse end cap marking "LF"

Tags: identification, components, fuses, markings

Does anybody know what this "LF" pair of characters mean on the fuse end cap?

[image: photo 1 of fuse end cap]

[image: photo 2 of fuse end cap]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the manufacturer's mark (Littelfuse).

Comment: The reference of the fuser is F8AH250VP, anyidea what the last P means?

Comment: Littelfuse has a somewhat confusing marking system for their cartridge fuses as the datasheet (https://www.littelfuse.com/media?resourcetype=datasheets&itemid=413d309a-e730-430e-b4a6-4e4a8686ee5c&filename=216-series-datasheet-update) gives the ordering part number but the cap number is found on a different sheet (https://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/files/littelfuse/technical-resources/documents/reference-documents/littelfuse_5x20mm-iec-fuse-cap-marking_guide.pdf).  I believe the P at the end stands for lead-free (Pb-free).